# how to document enum values in JS Doc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I am using JS Doc to generate docs for JS. I have an enum with few values. I want to generate docs for each property. I tried the following:

```
/**
 * Enum for display state.
 * @readonly
 * @enum {string}
 */
var DisplayState = {
    /** @member {string} */
    foreground: 'foreground',
    /** @member {string} */
    background: 'background',
    /** @member {string} */
    projected: 'projected'
};
```

But after HTML page is generated, I only see doc for enum type not individual properties.

I've tried the following /** some comment */  /** @member {string} */ And /** @property {string} */ but nothing seems to work

Comment: have you tried removing `@member`?

Comment: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-enum.html

Comment: Yes, I've tried 1. removing member 2. Adding property 3. removing member and property

Comment: what version of jsdoc?

Comment: JS Doc version 2.4.0

Comment: I've tried the following /** some comment */

Answer (score 5):

I upgraded to Version 3 of JS Doc (https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc) and this issue was fixed.

See example below:

```
/**
 * Enum for display state.
 * @readonly
 * @enum {string}
 */
var DisplayState = {
    /** @member {string} */
    /** The app is running in the foreground and can receive user input. */
    foreground: 'foreground',

    /** @member {string} */
    /** The app is in the background and can't receive user input. */
    background: 'background',

    /** @member {string} */
    /** The app is running in Phone Projection mode (Android Auto or Apple Car Play). */
    projected: 'projected'
};
```